# Anylogic: how to individually address to resources within a Resource Pool

Tags: anylogic

I am using Anylogic where I have just one ResourcePool made by just one Resource Type unit (created through the command "Resource Agent" in the Process Library).
I define the capacity of the ResourcePool, let's say, to 20 and I would like to have each of the single element (or some of them) within the Pool with a different value for the same parameter (e.g 3 units have parameter=1 , other 4 units parameter=2 ...).

First of all how can I set individually each of this parameter? Do I need to use a population of agent? If yes how can I do that? And how can I call the resourcePoolPopulation in other location within the model?

Is there a clevere way to do that?

Hope it is clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is a weak spot of resource pools, IMO. They are designed to hold a homogeneous "soup" of similar resources and it is hard to pull in a specific element.

However, not impossible, there are various ways. You can create your resource agents manually in an agent population first and add them to the pool manually after creation. Then, in the service object, tick "manual resource unit choice" (or similar) and use a criteria that matches your resource params.